# Localized SMS Text in Branch.io

Tags: branch.io

I'm trying to figure out how to created localized text using the $custom_sms_text in the TextMeTheApp feature in Branch.io

Am I correct that I need to setup a separate link for each language in order to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you ass to the `$custom_sms_text` is valid only for that link. So if you wish to have content in different languages, you will have to create an individual link for each language and add `$custom_sms_text` parameter to each link.

Comment: Thanks - this is a bummer - not very scalable, but at least I understand now.