# How Specify which link to use in SMS?

Tags: branch.io

Based on the answer in this question ([Localized SMS Text in Branch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502665/localized-sms-text-in-branch-io)) I need to setup different deep links for each language I want to support for the TextMeTheApp SMS.

How can I specify which link to use when triggering the SMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see the desktop redirect (`$desktop_url`) for the particular link to Text-me-the-app page(in case you are using the Branch default page) or to your webpage which would have a form for the users to input the phone number.

If you are using Branch's Text-me-the-app page it will automatically update the SMS with the custom text you specify in the `$custom_sms_text` you specify in the link.

If you are using your own web page, you will need to integrate Branch's web SDK on your web page (For more information on integrating the web SDK refer [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#integrate-app)). The flow would be as follows:

1. When a user clicks on the said link, they will be redirected to your web page.
2. Use Branch's web SDK to read the link parameters (Documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#read-deep-link))
3. Create your SMS with the link parameters from the data in the link. Make sure to add `$custom_sms_text` field. (Documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#create-text-message))
4. When the user receives the SMS, it will contain the text specified in the `$custom_sms_text`.

Comment: Can you provide a syntax example of using the `$custom_sms_text` field?